# Can someone please give me a simple explanation of group action?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't quite understand what group action is. Can someone explain group action to me in the simplest way possible?

What do I need to know about group actions and what are their properties?

Comment: The introductory paragraphs as well as the formal definition that follows are pretty good:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

Comment: "Groups really shine when you let them act on something" from *Algebra: Chapter 0* by Paolo Aluffi. By the way, I highly recommend Tim Gowers' [excellent blogpost](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/group-actions-i/) on understanding group actions.

Comment: Actually, a lot of groups are *defined* via some standard action of theirs (e.g. the symmetric group of permutations, the group of euclidean movements of the plane, ...).

Comment: The title of the question and the text says very different things. Here's an example of a group action: the group $S_3$ sends a triangle ABC to the triangle with permuted vertices.

Answer (score 2):

It is often said that groups are a mathematical way of expressing the symmetries of things.

A group action comes about when an object $S$ has symmetries which can be expressed as the elements of the group $G$.

The same abstract group can express the symmetries of many different objects - indeed $G$ need not express all the symmetries of $S$. We look at the abstract group when we want to study the properties common to all the objects on which $G$ acts - these are the properties of $G$.

We often study group actions in order to find out more about $G$ and its structure. If we understand some particular $S$ well, it may help us to understand $G$.

---

Note that the excellent post by Tim Gowers referred to in the comments reminds me that the group action need not be faithful - different group elements can act in the same way, and represent the same symmetry. The trivial action, where the elements of the group leave everything the same, is an extreme example.

Answer (score 0):

Well @kelly Group action is nothing but just a mapping $*$ from a group $G\times S\rightarrow S$ where $S$ is any non-empty set satisfying two properties i.e.

a.$g_1*(g_2*a)=(g_1g_2)*a \forall a\in S ;g_1,g_2\in G$

b.$e*a=a\forall a\in S; e $ is identity of $G$.

this is just the starting the most important part of Group Action according to me is the proof of Cayley's theorem using it